# Accessing Drupal Entity fields in custom templates

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

First of all let me say that this is my first project in Drupal and I am still confused, I apologize if my question is stupid.

I created a custom entity in Drupal 7 using Entity API. The custom entity represents a golf course.

I used this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/series/build-your-own-custom-entities-in-drupal/
Then I tried to add a custom theme, to do so I followed this: https://www.drupal.org/node/1238606

My callback function looks like this:

```
function view_golf_course($id) {
  $courses = entity_load('golf_course', array($id));
  $course = $courses[$id];
  drupal_set_title($course->name);
  $output = entity_view('golf_course', array($course));
  $output += array(
    '#theme'     => 'golf_course',
    '#element'   => $output,
    '#view_mode' => 'full',
    '#language'  => LANGUAGE_NONE,
  );
  return $output;
}
```

And this is my `hook_theme()`:

```
function golf_course_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'golf_course' => array(
      'variables' => array('element' => null),
      'template' => 'golf_course',
    ),
  );
}
```

The problem is that in `golf_course.tpl.php` I can only access the golf course variables this way (in this example I will access the address):

```
render($element['golf_course']['The Lakes Golf Club']['address']['#markup'])
```

As you can see, in order to access the address I have to use 'The Lakes Golf Club', (which is the name of the currently displayed golf course), as a key, but obviously that name is going to change every time I display a different golf course, so my question is:

How can I access the golf course attributes without having to use the golf course name as a key?

The documentation for `entity_view()` says:

> Return value
>
> The renderable array, keyed by the entity type and by entity
> identifiers, for which the entity name is used if existing - see
> entity_id(). If there is no information on how to view an entity,
> FALSE is returned.

So how do I avoid that the array is keyed by the name of the entity? If it was keyed by the id it would be OK because I have the `$id` variable in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer to this question:
if the result set of the query contains multiple rows, then entity_view will create an array with an empty index like so:

```
$element['golf_course']['']
```

and now you can access all entity fields of all rows in the result set by accessing the `['#entity']` array like so:

```
$element['golf_course']['']['#entity'] // all golf courses
$element['golf_course']['']['#entity'][0] // first golf course in the result set
$element['golf_course']['']['#entity'][0]['label'] // label of first golf course
$element['golf_course']['']['#entity'][0]['address'] // address of first golf course
```

On a side note, if your templates are in pure PHP you can just avoid using `entity_view()`, you will get a cleaner array (you don't have the `['golf_course']['']['#entity']` part).